# solving wave equation by factorization and change of variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve $$u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx},\quad u(x,0)=e^x,\quad u_t(x,0)=\sin x$$

Factoring, get $(\partial_t-c \partial_x)(\partial_t+c \partial_x)u=0$

Let $v=(\partial_t+c \partial_x)u$, and $(\partial_t-c\partial_x)v=0$.

Then how should I continue?

Comment: This is the wave equation. You may want to use the d'Alembert form $u(x,t) = F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$, or directly the corresponding [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $u(x,t) = F(x-c t)+G(x+c t)$ at the boundary conditions we have

$$
F(x)+G(x) = e^{x}\\
-F'(x)+G'(x) = \frac{\sin x}{c}
$$

now after deriving the first we have

$$
F'(x) = \frac 12\left(e^x+\frac{\sin x}{c}\right)\\
G'(x) = \frac 12\left(e^x-\frac{\sin x}{c}\right)\\
$$

etc.